# Scholarly package does return cropped output

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-scholar

I try to fetch some papers via scholarly, which works nicely. However, when I run

```
from scholarly import scholarly
from pprint import pprint

search_query = scholarly.search_pubs(query='Perception of physical stability and center of mass of 3D objects', year_low=2010)
pprint(next(search_query))
```

I receive

```
{'author_id': ['2efgcS0AAAAJ', '3hdOFF0AAAAJ', 'jTnQTBoAAAAJ', ''],
 'bib': {'abstract': 'in adulthood, we can perceive physical attributes in '
                     'just static  For 3D shape Vi, we have  four variables: a '
                     'shape type ti, and  stable in a different scene; and '
                     'which of the two objects is',
         'author': ['J Wu', 'I Yildirim', 'JJ Lim', 'B Freeman'],
         'pub_year': '2015',
         'title': 'Galileo: Perceiving physical object properties by '
                  'integrating a physics engine with deep learning',
         'venue': 'Advances in neural …'},
 'citedby_url': '/scholar?cites=13801231000054551969&as_sdt=5,33&sciodt=0,33&hl=en',
 'container_type': 'Publication',
 'eprint_url': 'https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/file/d09bf41544a3365a46c9077ebb5e35c3-Paper.pdf',
 'filled': False,
 'gsrank': 1,
 'num_citations': 398,
 'pub_url': 'https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2015/hash/d09bf41544a3365a46c9077ebb5e35c3-Abstract.html',
 'source': <PublicationSource.PUBLICATION_SEARCH_SNIPPET: 'PUBLICATION_SEARCH_SNIPPET'>,
 'url_add_sclib': '/citations?hl=en&xsrf=&continue=/scholar%3Fq%3DPerception%2Bof%2Bphysical%2Bstability%2Band%2Bcenter%2Bof%2Bmass%2Bof%2B3D%2Bobjects%26hl%3Den%26as_sdt%3D0,33%26as_ylo%3D2010&citilm=1&update_op=library_add&info=oVVc9XjSh78J&ei=zwj2Za2PCNGcy9YP4-WF0A8&json=',
 'url_related_articles': '/scholar?q=related:oVVc9XjSh78J:scholar.google.com/&scioq=Perception+of+physical+stability+and+center+of+mass+of+3D+objects&hl=en&as_sdt=0,33&as_ylo=2010',
 'url_scholarbib': '/scholar?hl=en&q=info:oVVc9XjSh78J:scholar.google.com/&output=cite&scirp=0&hl=en'}
```

Hence, in `bib`, both the `abstract` and the `venue` is cropped.

Do you know how fix that?